# how to make the footer stick to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

i have a problem with keeping the footer stick to the bottom
i havn't added styles to the footer i just made it the last element in the page and it works fine , until there is a page with small content , then the footer move up like in this picture
[image]

now what could i do to make the footer stick to bottom when page content has small height.

i tried to add theise styles to the footer :

```
footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0; }
```

this works fine if the page has small content but if it's not the footer gets displayed on top of the page content like this picture :
[image]

bottom line is how could i make this footer stick to bottom

Comment: calculate footer height and give same  padding-bottom to the parent div

Comment: You'll have to show some HTML code to get a proper answer, but most likely all you have ot do is set `min-height: 100vh;` on the parent element which holds the footer&main&header elements (probably the `<body>`)

Comment: i already added that to the body but the problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: didn't work :( .